Failure in loading components referencing third party libraries loaded as static resource
We have a built a component to visualize data on the map from ArcGIS. We are using the ArcGIS JS API (third party library). This component is within a 2GP package.
Just to give you some more context on where and how we are referencing the library. We have built an LWC component which loads a Visualforce page within an Iframe, and the Visualforce page references the ArcGIS JS API.
LWC -> iFrame -> Vf Page -> ArcGIS JS API in Static Resource
ArcGIS JS API is a big library ~45MB and since we want this package to pass security review, we use Webpack tool to bundle up the necessary modules needed for the component to work.
We then upload this bundle as a zip file (<5MB) into a static resource, and import it into the Visualforce page.
The above component works as expected in the backend Salesforce Platform. However when we use the same component in the Digital Experience site, it throws errors in the browser console regarding some of the custom components from within the third-party library. Due to which our component fails load all of the elements.
When we use "Relaxed CSP" and turn off Lightning Locker in the Experience Builder the component start to work just fine.
We would like to know what is the best way to handle such components in both backend Salesforce as well as in the Experience Sites. We do not think turning off Lightning Locker is a best practice, so we would like to know if there is an alternative to solve this problem without having to turn off Lightning Locker.
